# How to capture the event on clicking the arrow icon in tree grid

Tags: dojo, expand

I am trying to call a function by clicking the arrow icon in treegrid.
I tried using onRowClick, but the function I use accepts rowData whereas rowClick return the event. How do i extract the information from event and pass it to rowData.

```
dojo.connect(grid, "onRowClick", formatIcon);

//Function Definiton
formatIcon(rowData){
//do something with rowData
}
```

with this i face issue rowData is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to catch the onClick event from your Dijit Tree Node.

```
onClick(item, node, evt)
```

More info can be found here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_Tree_onClick